# Visual Sudio 2010 Drag&Drop not working

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I just want to copy a file path but unfortunately I am not able to do that. The funny thing is that `syntaxEdit_DragEnter` is executed but `syntaxEdit_DragDrop` isn't!

```
private void syntaxEdit_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter allow D&D "  + this.syntaxEdit.AllowDrop.ToString());
}

private void syntaxEdit_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("syntaxEdit_DragDrop");
}
```

`syntaxEdit` initalisazion:

```
this.syntaxEdit.AllowDrop = true;
this.syntaxEdit.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.syntaxEdit_DragDrop);
this.syntaxEdit.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.syntaxEdit_DragEnter);
```

PS: I am not running VS as admin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `e.Effect` in `DragEnter` to something other than `None` to tell the system that the item can be dropped there.

Comment: I set it to `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;` but `syntaxEdit_DragDrop` still does not get called.

Comment: @StefanFalk: Try handling DragOver instead.

Comment: But the event should only be handled if the users releases the mousebutton. Shouldn't `DragDrop` event handle that?

Comment: @StefanFalk: I mean instead of `DragEnter`.